# React Table error and don't have CSS file

Tags: reactjs, react-table-v7

[image]

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';

class Table extends Component {

    render() {
        const tableData = [{name:"Saiful",age:"28"},{name:"Saiful",age:"28"},{name:"Saiful",age:"28"},{name:"Saiful",age:"28"}]

        const tableColumns = [{Header: "Name", accessor: "name"},{Header: "Age", accessor: "age"}]


        return (
            <div>
                <ReactTable
                    data = {tableData}
                    columns = {tableColumns}
                    defaultPageSize={2}
                    pageSizeOptions={[2,4,6,8]}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: Could you post the code in `app.js` file, where you import `Table`?

Comment: Another question, I have checked the documentation for react-table and did not find an example using ReactTable component? . To be honest, I checked the quick start section very fast.

Comment: import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Test from "./mycomponents/Test";
import Post from "./mycomponents/Post";
import DataTable from "./mycomponents/DataTable";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        {/*<Post></Post>*/}
        {/*<Test></Test>*/}
        <DataTable></DataTable>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Comment: try to change <DataTable> to <Table>, both in the import statement, and in the app function

Comment: At Frist, I use <Table> but don't work..And react-table don't have any CSS file